# smoothScrollToPositionFromTop not smooth when going to a lower index

Tags: android, listview

I need my listview to scroll at a specific position at any time, putting the row at this position at the top of the listview.

For this purpose I use `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int position, int offset, int duration)`

Now let's say I wand to go from index 6 to 10, it scrolls smoothly. After that let's say I want to go backward, 5 for instance, the scrolling is not smooth at all, it looks like a rapid translation.

Any idea what I could be missing or any workaround?

Comment: Is the relative -5 element visible when the second smooth scroll happens?

Comment: no they are not visible, probably why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had to use a workaround, basically:

```
int topPosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
if (targetPosition > topPosition) {
    mListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(targetPosition, 0, duration);
} else if (targetPosition < topPosition) {
    View firstView = mListViewWeeks.getChildAt(0);
    int height = firstView.getHeight();
    mListView.smoothScrollBy(-height * (topPosition - targetPosition), duration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop()` while going *back* is what is causing your problem.

Prefer the use of `smoothScrollToPosition()`.

Comment: smoothScrollToPosition() works well indeed but keep the selected row at the bottom of the listview. How to keep it to the top?

Comment: That I don't know. Sorry my answer did not help.